# Trouble with FIFO

Tags: c, struct, fifo

I'm trying to create FIFO with struct but it's not working, I'm trying to find out what's wrong with my code since yesterday night. It's only prototype and so far everything my code does is store information. Apparently it is not doing even it.

```
 #define TAM 10

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <locale.h>


        typedef struct
        {

            int final;
            int inicio;
            int tamanho;   
            int contador;

            char *vetorFila[TAM];

        }  pretendentes;


        void entrarComDadosLista();
        void armazenarDadosLista();


        int main(void)
        {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "");        


            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
            {
                pretendentes -> vetorFila[i] = NULL;
            }


            entrarComDadosLista();


            return 0;
        }



        void entrarComDadosLista()
        {
            static char nomes[10], *ptr;

            printf("Digite o nome ou aperte ENTER para sair.\n\n");
            do
            {
                printf("Digite o nome do pretendente: ");
                scanf("%s", nomes);

                ptr = (char*) malloc(strlen(nomes));
                strcpy(ptr,       nomes);
                armazenarDadosLista(ptr);       

            } while(*nomes);
        }



        void armazenarDadosLista(pretendentes *Pretendente, char *nomes)
        {
            if(Pretendente -> inicio == TAM)
            {
                printf("A fila está cheia.");
                return 0;
            }

            Pretendente -> vetorFila[Pretendente->inicio] = nomes;
            Pretendente -> inicio++;

        }
```

Can someone give me hand to find my error? The code does compile but it stops working after few entries. I just wanna check if the names are being stored in the fifo.

Comment: Are you sure this compiles?  Better take a good look at the compiler output and check all warnings.

Comment: `armazenarDadosLista(ptr);` is not a good way to call `armazenarDadosLista(pretendentes *, char *)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found:

```
// (1) declare "armazenarDadosLista" as a function accepting
//     an unknown number of arguments that each have an unknown type
void armazenarDadosLista();
...
// (2) in "entrarComDadosLista", call "armazenarDadosLista" with
//     1 argument: ptr
armazenarDadosLista(ptr);
...
// (3) declare "armazenarDadosLista" as a function accepting
//     2 arguments: pretendentes* , char*
void armazenarDadosLista(pretendentes *Pretendente, char *nomes) {
}
```

If you change `(1)` to match `(3)`, the compiler will complain because you call `armazenarDadosLista` with an incorrect number of arguments.  Instead of using `void function_name();` for all functions, declare them with the correct number and types of arguments, so the compiler can help you when you do something like `armazenarDadosLista(ptr)`:

```
void entrarComDadosLista(void);
void armazenarDadosLista(pretendentes *Pretendente, char *nomes);
```

Comment: But then there still is `pretendentes->`

Comment: I considered that to be a code reproduction error. I agree that the code shouldn't compile as presented, but if it did, the problem is in calling the function with the wrong number of arguments.